# Understanding complex type declaration in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0, typescript2.3

Looking at a this type declaration:

```
export interface Thenable<R> {
    then<U>(onFulfilled?: (value: R) => U | Thenable<U>, onRejected?: (error: any) => U | Thenable<U>): Thenable<U>
    then<U>(onFulfilled?: (value: R) => U | Thenable<U>, onRejected?: (error: any) => void): Thenable<U>
    catch<U>(onRejected?: (error: any) => U | Thenable<U>): Thenable<U>
}
```

I'm aware of what it does. I can do something like this:

```
type MessagesSendResponse = ...
export const announce = (options: sendParameters):Thenable<MessagesSendResponse> => {
 return Promise.all([emailMessage(options),smsMessage(options)] 
}
```

This makes it smart enough to know that in context

```
const val1 = announce(..)
```

that `val1` is a Thenable/Promise whereas in this context

```
const val2 = await announce(..)
```

`val2` is of type `MessagesSendResponse`

My question is that I don't understand the following about the `Thenable` interface:

1. What does it mean to say `Thenable<U>` I understand that `U` is a generic type, yet what does `Thenable<U>` mean? What's another way to write that?
2. Somehow this definition is saying that a function returns a thenable / promise that in turn returns a generic. Yet both the interface type and the return value for both `then` and `catch` are of type `Thenable<U>`. It looks like its saying that it returns itself, which I suppose is right since a thenable can return another thenable, but how does it know that it know that the resolution is `MessagesSemdResponse` if it says it returns `Thenable<U>`? Is there some build in feature in the IDE for this?

I realize question 2 reflect my confusion. Any links to references appreciated, I couldn't find anything similar to this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

part1:

```
export interface Thenable<R> {
```

we are defining generic interface with one type parameter `R`

part2:

```
then<U>(onFulfilled?: ...,  onRejected?: ...): ...
```

it has method `then`, which takes two parameters `onFulfilled` and `onRejected`, and the method itself is generic - it depends on another type paramerer `U`.

part3, the most interesting one:

`onFulfilled` is declared with this type:

```
(value: R) => U | Thenable<U>
```

it means that it's either a function taking `R` and returning `U`, or another `Thenable<U>`

Here is a relationship between `R` and `U`: if you have `Thenable<R>`, it's `then` method accepts a callback which is called with a value of type `R` (the one that original thenable produced), and should return `U`. Or it can accept another `Thenable<U>`.

The return value of this `then` method, then, is `Thenable<U>`.

In short, this is how chaining of promises is described with types.

Answer (score 3):

`Thenable<T>` means that you have an object from which you can obtain a value of type `T`.
Or, if naming it `Promise<T>` you get a promise to a value of type `T`.

Because promises are usually used for asynchronous operations, the promise doesn't "return a value" but gives you an api for getting a reference to that value when it is available.

The reason that `then`/`catch` return `Thenable<T>` is so that you can chain the calls:

```
announce(...).then(value => {
    ...
}).catch(error => {
    ...
});
```

The function that you are passing to `then`/`catch` will be called upon when the value is available or when something went wrong.

The promise that is being returned by `then`/`catch` is not the same promise that you called the function on, it's a new instance, and the compiler infers the generic type of this new promise based on the return value of the function you passed, for example:

```
const fn = (): Promise<string> => {
    return Promise.resolve("43"); 
}

fn().then(str => Number(str)).then(num => console.log(num))
```

The compiler knows that `str` is of type `string` and that `num` is of type `number`.

You can read more about this process here: [promise chaining in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining)

---

#### Edit

In the signature:

```
then<U>(onFulfilled?: (value: R) => U | Thenable<U>, onRejected?: (error: any) => U | Thenable<U>): Thenable<U>
```

**onFulfilled**:
A function that expects a value of type `R` and returns either a value of type `U` or a `Thenable` to `U`.

**onRejected**:
A function that expects a value of type `any` and returns either a value of type `U` or a `Thenable` to `U`.

**returns**:
A instance of `Thenable` for a value of type `U`, which is the result of the execution of either `onFulfilled` or `onRejected`.

Comment: Thanks, so what does the line ` then<U>(onFulfilled?: (value: R) => U | Thenable<U>, onRejected?: (error: any) => U | Thenable<U>): Thenable<U>` express to the compiler?

Comment: check my revised answer